# Can this javascript oauth call be represented in POSTMAN? (or c#)

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, postman

I have a API I am trying to test out. They sent me this javascript so I tried to imitate it below. Now sure how to do it in postman

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {grant_type: 'client_credentials'},
    url: 'http://192.168.240.6:9080/somecompany/auth/oauth/token',
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
      var clientID = 'c39692d9-8998-497f-8ea2-7503be9fc8c1',
          clientSecret = 'befb744f-37f5-491d-8d57-e8e5c1419f2e',
          authKey = btoa(clientID + ':' + clientSecret);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authKey);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific screen in Postman (The Oauth form) will not allow you to pass the "Authorization" header. The request in the code snippet represents a step in the oauth's `client_credentials` flow (see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-40)), while the Postman form in the screenshot is the first one in (Authorization Code or Implict ones)(see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-40)).

If you want to replicate exactly what is in the example, you will have to construct a POST request in Postman, adding manually the headers and the payload used in the example.

But also, besides that, you will still miss the encoded string generated by the *btoa* function in the javascript example. If your intention is to just test it manually, you can execute `btoa(clientID + ':' + clientSecret)` manually and paste the result in Postman headers configuration.

ps:  I strongly recommend you to read about the different grant flows that Oauth supports.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the fundamentals. I thought the first part is to POST a key/secret and then get back a token. I thought that was the screen above in postman. What you are saying is just ignore that screen and just do a standard POST in Postman using th eURL and a entry in the header (that encrypted key/secret). Am I right so far ?

Comment: In the end I will want to call it from a c# console app so I just need to translate that javascript code above into c#. Ill try that now...